# BigQuery LOAD_JOB with field that is sometimes an ARRAY and sometimes a single STRING value

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, schema, load

Attached is a screenshot of the actual json causing issues. The field subcategory is sometimes a single string value "compulsory" and sometimes an array ["compulsory", "court_order"]

As such I have set the schema "mode" to REPEATABLE, but this does not allow the capture of both types of data.

My question is simply do I have to directly edit the JSON such that "compulsory" becomes explicitly ["compulsory"] or is there an in-built option somewhere that will allow this?

This feels like a common issue.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I guess you have the issue already in the load job. Then you need to edit the JSON before loading, as you suggested. If the JSON is loaded as string in the BigQuery table, then it is possible to the correct it with a JavaScript UDF.

Comment: Hi @David Kane, did the above comment help?

Answer (score 1):

You can also pre-process your file prior to loading it to BigQuery using your preferred programming language. Python code below converts non lists value of  `"subcategory"` to a list so your data type for it will be uniform.

```py
import json

# {
#   "data": [
#     {
#       "subcategory": "compulsory",
#       "type": "WU04"
#     },
#     {
#       "subcategory": [
#         "compulsory",
#         "court-order"
#       ],
#       "type": "WU04"
#     }
#   ]
# }

f = open("sample.json")

data_dict = json.load(f)

for entry in data_dict["data"]:
    if not(isinstance(entry["subcategory"],list)):
        entry["subcategory"] = [entry["subcategory"]]

with open("new_sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data_dict, outfile,indent=2)
```

Output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "subcategory": [
        "compulsory"
      ],
      "type": "WU04"
    },
    {
      "subcategory": [
        "compulsory",
        "court-order"
      ],
      "type": "WU04"
    }
  ]
}
```

NOTE: I created a simple sample data just to illustrate the logic behind the said approach. Adjust the code accordingly if your JSON structure is different.